# Installing pip in centOS 7

Tags: python, linux, pip, centos, centos7

When I installed **python3.8**, It also installed pip
`Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.1.1)`
but when I do `which pip` I get an error

> /usr/bin/which: no pip in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin)

Also when I do `pip --version` I get an error

> -bash: pip: command not found

How do I get to use the installed **pip**

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for installing pip will be:

```
yum install pythonX-pip
```

Where X is the version of python you are currently running.

Comment: I did that and got ``Package python3-pip-9.0.3-8.el7.noarch already installed and latest version``. But when typed ``pip -V`` i got an error ``bash: pip: command not found``

Comment: Run rpm -q -l python3-pip-9.0.3-8.el7.noarch. This will show the path to the pip executable. You can then add it to your PATH environmental variable.